# How to separate FCM notification on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have two different notification. 

One is a message while the other is notification for something else. 

I want to separate the notification. 

For example, when I receive notification messages and I tap it, it opens the chat room, while the other one opens another activity.

Comment: you can differentiate by type in custom payload in body of FCM

Comment: hello how can i do this

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here are some of the basic properties required to the send downstream messages.**

**to** – *Type String – (Optional) [Recipient of a message]
The value must be a single registration token, notification key, or topic. Do not set this field when sending to multiple topics*

**registration_ids** *– Type String array – (Optional) [Recipients of a message]
Multiple registration tokens, min 1 max 1000.*

**priority** *– Type String – (Optional) [ default normal]
Allowed values normal and high.*

**delay_while_idle** *– Type boolean – (Optional) [default value false]
true indicates that the message should not be sent until the device becomes active.*

**time_to_live** *– Type JSON number – (Optional) [default value 4 week maximum 4 week]
This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline*

**data**  *– Type JSON Object
Specifies the custom key-value pairs of the message’s payload. 
eg.* **{“post_id”:”1234″,”post_title”:”A Blog Post Title”}**

In Android you can receive it in **onMessageReceived()** as Map data…

```
public class FcmMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //onMessageReceived will be called when ever you receive new message from server.. (app in background and foreground )
        Log.d("FCM", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
        Log.d("FCM", "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("post_id") && remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("post_title")){
            Log.d("Post ID",remoteMessage.getData().get("post_id").toString());
            Log.d("Post Title",remoteMessage.getData().get("post_title").toString());
            // eg. Server Send Structure data:{"post_id":"12345","post_title":"A Blog Post"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Where is a type of notification (message,notif) show me the json thanks

Comment: this is ans example but you can use 
{"type":"type1", “post_id”:”1234″,”post_title”:”A Blog Post Title”}

Comment: Good Job..THank You Vishal

Comment: Welcome @JinalPatel :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you should use the [click_action](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) field, that allows you to specify the Activity you want to launch when the user taps on the notification.

So in your notification payload:

```
click_action: "<intent to launch>"
```

If not defined then the click_action defaults to the launcher Intent/Activity.